# flutter_inappwebview How do I put a list of websites into content blockers?

Tags: flutter, dart

In my flutter app I am using [flutter_inappwebview](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview/versions/5.1.0). How to put LIST from web sites into urlFilter method?

```
contentBlockers: [
          ContentBlocker(
            trigger: ContentBlockerTrigger(
              urlFilter: "https://.*LIST*",
              // resourceType: [ContentBlockerTriggerResourceType.SCRIPT],
            ),
            action: ContentBlockerAction(
              type: ContentBlockerActionType.BLOCK,
              // selector: 'div',
            ),
          ),
        ],
```

UPDATE:
I found an article like this [URL Category Exception Lists](https://docs.paloaltonetworks.com/pan-os/8-1/pan-os-admin/url-filtering/url-filtering-concepts/block-and-allow-lists.html)
But I don't see a method to list from sites like `site.com`, `site-two.org`, `website.info` ...